# How do I find the number of objects being created in a Java program?

Tags: java, class, object

The code presented should count the objects created.

I expected it to create three objects and a `count` of `3` to be printed.

This only prints out 1. I think because the object name `Number_Objects obj` is the same in all three of the methods. How do I change the program so that it returns `3` (creation of three objects)?

```
public class Number_Objects {
    static int count = 0;

    Number_Objects() {
        count++;
    }

    public void Number_Objectstest1() {
        Number_Objects obj = new Number_Objects();
    }

    public void Number_Objectstest2() {
        Number_Objects obj = new Number_Objects();
    }

    public void Number_Objectstest3() {
        Number_Objects obj = new Number_Objects();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you printing out to return 1? There doesn't seem to be any print/return code here.

Comment: The above code prints nothing. Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. And no, the name of the reference in your source code doen't affect that counter at all. So whatever creates your problem, it is not in the code you are sharing with us!

Comment: **`Java != Javascript`**. Java is to Javascript what Car is to Carpet.

Comment: How can it return 1? You're not instantiating anything

Comment: @MCEmperor this should be a quote :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you presented does basically nothing but printing text. Especially, it will not output `1`, it outputs `0`.

This is because you are updating the `count` variable in the constructor of your class (which is badly named, btw. Please review naming schemes in Java), yet, the constructor is never called, because you create no instances.

To receive the result three, you need to create three instances of the class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Number_Objects one = new Number_Objects();
    System.out.println( Number_Objects.count ); // --> 1

    Number_Objects two = new Number_Objects();
    System.out.println( Number_Objects.count ); // --> 2

    Number_Objects three = new Number_Objects();
    System.out.println( Number_Objects.count ); // --> 3
}
```

Each `new` will allocate memory for the instance of the class created and call the appropriate constructor, matching the parameters you give.

Comment: Thank you! That cleared my doubt!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an object inside the method. But you are not executing that function which means the object has not been created yet. Call your methods in the main method.

**P.S.** Java != JavaScript

```
class NumberObjects {

  static int count = 0;

  NumberObjects() {
      count++;
  }

  public static void NumberObjectstest1() {
      NumberObjects obj = new NumberObjects();
  }

  public static void NumberObjectstest2() {
      NumberObjects obj = new NumberObjects();
  }

  public static void NumberObjectstest3() {
      NumberObjects obj = new NumberObjects();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      NumberObjectstest1();
      NumberObjectstest2();
      NumberObjectstest3();
      System.out.println(count);
  }
}
```